# cakephp query with conditions limit and order

Tags: mysql, cakephp, mysql-error-1064

I want to retrieve the last 3 registered users in cakephp using the field `created` in table `Users`.

In my controller I have:

```
$this->User->recursive = 1;
    $this->set('users',
        $this->User->find('all',
             array('conditions'=> array(
                  'limit' => 3,
                  'order' => array(
                  'created' => 'asc'
                  )
             )
         )
    )
);
```

The code above when run returns this error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'order = ('asc')' at line
```

What must I do to resolve the error?

Comment: `conditions`, `limit` & `order` should be the same level :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$this->set('users', $this->User->find('all', array(
    'limit' => 3,
    'order' => 'User.created DESC',
    'recursive' => 1,
)));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Keep your order and limit out side of condition array then it will work smoothly.**

Use this format:

```
array(
'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
'recursive' => 1, //int
'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
'limit' => n, //int
'page' => n, //int
'offset' => n, //int
'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily also select your data by this is sql query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where recursive =1 order by created desc limit 0,3";
$users = $this->users->query($sql);

$this->set(compact('users'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try code like given below:

```
 $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all', array(
                                        'order' => 'created ASC',
                                        'limit' => 3  )
            ));
```

Please refer to [this link](http://www.devdaily.com/php/cakephp-find-conditions-cakephp-find-all-list-count) for CakePHP find conditions.

Answer (score 1):

When you limit the data first you should order `DESC or ASC`. Another easy way that works fine

```
$this->set('datas',
    $this->Your_Model_Name->find('all',
        array (
            'conditions'    => array('Site_id' => $site_name),   //conditions here
            'fields'        => array('Date_time','Ac_1_Status','Tempin'),
            'order'         => array('id' => 'desc'),  // id desc or asc
            'limit'         => 15
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dashreport =  $this->Task->find('all', array('conditions' => 
                array('Task.throttle' => "Report", 'Task.status' => Null, 'Task.userid' => $this->Session->read('userid')),'order'=>array('Task.id DESC')
                ,'limit'=> 4));
```