# Custom query pagination in cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have a query as below in controller with multiple joins

```
$deals = $this->Deals->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Deals.id',
        'Deals.deed_amount',
        'Deals.other_amount',
        'Deals.cash_amount',
        'Deals.total_amount',
        'Deals.client_id',
        'Deals.project_id',
        'Deals.property_id',
        'Deals.properties_flat_id',
        'Deals.date',
        'Deals.status',
        'Deals.invoice_no',
        'Deals.remain_cash_amount',
        'Deals.remain_deed_amount',
        'Deals.remain_other_amount',
        'Deals.remain_deed_amount',
        'Property.name',
        'Client.name',
        'PropertyFlat.name',
        'PropertyFlat.status'


    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'properties',
            'alias' => 'Property',
            'type'  => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Deals.property_id = Property.id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'clients',
            'alias' => 'Client',
            'type'  => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Deals.client_id = Client.id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'properties_flats',
            'alias' => 'PropertyFlat',
            'type'  => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Deals.properties_flat_id = PropertyFlat.id'
            )
        )

    ),

   // 'conditions'=>$condition


));
```

I want to add pagination to the view. I tried following

```
$this->set('deals', $this->Paginator->paginate($deals));
```

But no use. Please help me in how to add pagination for the custom query. I searched many links but did not get any help.

Comment: You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274146/cakephp-query-with-conditions-limit-and-order

Comment: i want to add pagination for custom query

Comment: you need to add limit and page params in array

Comment: how do you join along with pagination

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
       $paginate = [
                        'joins' =>  array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'properties',
                    'alias' => 'Property',
                    'type'  => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Deals.property_id = Property.id'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'clients',
                    'alias' => 'Client',
                    'type'  => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Deals.client_id = Client.id'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'properties_flats',
                    'alias' => 'PropertyFlat',
                    'type'  => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Deals.properties_flat_id = PropertyFlat.id'
                    )
                )

            ),
    'fields' => array(
            'Deals.id',
            'Deals.deed_amount',
            'Deals.other_amount',
            'Deals.cash_amount',
            'Deals.total_amount',
            'Deals.client_id',
            'Deals.project_id',
            'Deals.property_id',
            'Deals.properties_flat_id',
            'Deals.date',
            'Deals.status',
            'Deals.invoice_no',
            'Deals.remain_cash_amount',
            'Deals.remain_deed_amount',
            'Deals.remain_other_amount',
            'Deals.remain_deed_amount',
            'Property.name',
            'Client.name',
            'PropertyFlat.name',
            'PropertyFlat.status'


        )
   ];
 $this->set('deals', $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Deals->find('all'), $paginate)->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend to rethink the way you have constructed your query. Why don't you just use the contain() method to retrieve the associated data?

Secondly, You can use custom finders with the paginator. Just create one in your Table class and return constructed query from it and ask the paginator to use it. Read more here. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html